# How can I convert a Harmony One address to an Ethereum address?

Tags: addresses, harmony

Harmony addresses have a special format like this: `one1y6l5rxhpj65wefqvpme90hlg6alt2ttxcnjel5` and they have their counterpart in Ethereum like this one: `0x26bf419ae196a8eca40c0ef257dfe8d77eb52d66`.

The Harmony block explorer is able to convert them: https://explorer.harmony.one/address/0x26bf419ae196a8eca40c0ef257dfe8d77eb52d66

But I haven't found a way to do so programmatically. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

python:

```
from bip_utils.addr.one_addr import OneAddrDecoder
print(OneAddrDecoder().DecodeAddr("ADDRESS").hex())
```